# Why is it "you look beautiful" and not "you look beautifully"?

Tags: sentence-construction, adjectives, adverbs

> You look **beautiful**

"Beautiful" is an adjective here. We often use "adverbs" to modify "verbs". Here the verb is "look" and instead of an adverb, we have an adjective "beautiful". Shouldn't it be:

> You look **beautifully**

?

Two other examples are:

- I work **hard** (instead of hardly)
- He looks **handsome** (not handsomely)

Do the adjectives work as adverbs here or it is another grammatical construction that I don't know?

Comment: "Look" is a copula here. This has been answered before. Please check out the answer in the post I am pointing you to. It should sufficiently answer your question.

Comment: @EddieKal Thanks. It does answer my question, more than sufficiently ;-)